# X is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django

I'm experimenting with django.

```
from import_export import resources


class Settings1(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Settings2(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    settings2 = models.OneToOneField(Settings1)
```

When I'm trying to create Settings2 object instance it gives me this error

```
s2 = models.Settings2(bar='bar', settings2=settings)

'settings2' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: Where are you trying to create this instance?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved with restart of django shell.